# "'signOut' is not exported from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'" when following AWS Amplify tutorial

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm following the AWS "Build A React App using Amplify" tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-two).  I'm on Step 5 of Module 3, which states the following:

> Next, open src/App.js and update with the following code:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";
import {
  withAuthenticator,
  Button,
  Heading,
  Image,
  View,
  Card,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

function App({ signOut }) {
  return (
    <View className="App">
      <Card>
        <Image src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Heading level={1}>We now have Auth!</Heading>
      </Card>
      <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</Button>
    </View>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

> In this code, we've used the withAuthenticator component. This component will scaffold out an entire user authentication flow allowing users to sign up, sign in, reset their password, and confirm sign-in for multifactor authentication (MFA). We have also added a Sign Out button to log users out.

I did exactly as instructed and waited for my code to re-compile, but when it did, I saw the following error:

```
src/App.js
  Line 21:24:  'signOut' is not defined  no-undef
```

OK, no problem, maybe the tutorial simply left out the `signOut` function from the `import` statement.  I added it like so:

```
import {
  withAuthenticator,
  Button,
  Heading,
  Image,
  View,
  Card,
  signOut,
} from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
```

However, now I get the following error in my terminal:

```
Attempted import error: 'signOut' is not exported from '@aws-amplify/ui-react' (imported as 'signOut').
ERROR in ./src/App.js 34:15-22
export 'signOut' (imported as 'signOut') was not found in '@aws-amplify/ui-react'

(possible exports: AccountSettings, Alert, AmplifyProvider, Authenticator, Autocomplete, 
Badge, Button, ButtonGroup, Card, CheckboxField, Collection, ComponentClassNames, 
ComponentClassObject, ComponentPropsToStylePropsMap, ComponentPropsToStylePropsMapKeys, 
Divider, Expander, ExpanderItem, FieldGroupIcon, FieldGroupIconButton, FileUploader, 
Flex, Geocoder, Grid, Heading, HighlightMatch, Icon, Image, InAppMessageDisplay, 
InAppMessagingProvider, Link, Loader, LocationSearch, MapView, Menu, MenuButton, 
MenuItem, Pagination, PasswordField, PhoneNumberField, Placeholder, Radio, 
RadioGroupField, Rating, ScrollView, SearchField, SelectField, SliderField, StepperField, 
SwitchField, TabItem, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableFoot, TableHead, TableRow, Tabs, 
Text, TextAreaField, TextField, ThemeProvider, ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup, View, 
VisuallyHidden, components, createTheme, defaultDarkModeOverride, defaultTheme, 
primitives, translations, useAmplify, useAuthenticator, useBreakpointValue, 
useInAppMessaging, usePagination, useTheme, withAuthenticator, withInAppMessaging)
```

I don't see anything which looks related to sign-out functionality listed among the `possible exports` section of the error message.

What am I missing here?  I'd love to know both how to fix the immediate error, as well as how I could have debugged this issue on my own, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Googling "sign out react amplify aws" and found [this page](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-out), which implements a function called `signOut`:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signOut() {
    try {
        await Auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    }
}
```

First I removed my original attempt to import `signOut` via the `"@aws-amplify/ui-react"` import statement.  After that, simply copy-pasting this code into my `src/App.js` file provided me with the functionality I needed to keep moving forward.

I subsequently scoured the tutorial for this same code, but it's nowhere to be found.  Not sure why that is, I'm guessing it was an accidental oversight on AWS's part?